Why do flex-row and justify-items-center classes have no effect on Firefox but work on Chrome?


function App() {
  return ( 
    <div className = "flex-row justify-items-center" >
      <h1> MINIMAL LOL </h1>
    </div >
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



This works as intended on Chrome:

However this is the result on Firefox:

When inspected on Firefox the flex-row class is grayed out and when hovered shows a tooltip "flex-direction has no effect on this element since it’s not a flex container".
The justify-items-center is also grayed out and shows a tooltip "justify-items has no effect on this element since it’s not a grid container".
Why is there a difference between Firefox and Chrome in rendering this classes?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Paulie_D I added what you requested above and thank you for the reminder.

Sorry, I don't think it's enough to tell people to go to another site and build a runnable snippet themselves. Put a snippet we can run into your question using <> in the editor.

@AHaworth I added that as well thank you

Reproducable on Windows Firefox 133. This is probably a bug in Firefox as justify-items should be working in a normal block-level layout.

Just wanted to add on that on Safari ios the same happens

justify-items is not implemented for block-level layouts in Firefox yet. They have a new ticket opened for this 3 weeks ago.
justify-items:center should be working in block level layouts as mentioned in mdn and draft spec:

In block-level layouts, it aligns the items inside their containing block on the inline axis.

For now, you can just use text-center if that's all you need, or else you'll need to use it along with grid.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1> MINIMAL LOL </h1>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you this does answer my question of why there's a difference between Firefox and Chrome. The code provided does fix the issue of the minimal code example I shared but in my case I have other components inside and I should find another solution. However it is finally good to know I am not at fault, thank you.

np! Forgot to mention, but you are seeing the tool tip because flex-row needs to be along with flex. However, flex won't work with justify-items so they don't go together anyway.
